# How can I send a background 'warmup' request to GAE from a static HTML page?

Tags: jquery, html, google-app-engine, asynchronous

For applications which do not attract much traffic, the initial startup can take many seconds, but static HTML pages appear almost instantly.

So my idea is to put some information on the static index.html and run an asynchronous warmup request from Javascript in the background. So if the browser hits index.html, the script would 'wake up' the GAE application while the user is still busy reading the information on the home page.

My question is: how could I dynamically render a 'loading ...' message from a background Javascript using jQuery? Or, to keep it very simple, just run a GET request and discard the result.

Could I simply add

```
jQuery.ajax("non-static-url");
```

to the jQuery(document).ready(function() ... code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/url_here.php'
  });
});
</script>
```

If you wanted to have a loading message that disappeared when the warm-up was done, just render the page with an element like this:

```
<span id="loading-msg">Loading...</span>
```

and change the jquery ajax request to have a success handler, like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/url_here.php',
    success: function() {
      $("#loading-msg").remove();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```